# What's the correct way to get a Unix timestamp in Go

Tags: time, go, timestamp, unix-timestamp

What's the correct way to get the Unix timestamp in Go? I thought it would be `time.Now().Unix()` but it's clearly not.

[image]

http://play.golang.org/p/KoJADUDxOS

[image]

So `time.Now().Unix()` tells me the unix timestamp is **1257894000** whereas my browser tells me it is **1398351437**. Also www.unixtimestamp.de tells me it is **1398351704** which is what I would expect. Why is the one coming from Go so far off? I get the same results on my local machine btw.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

Ok, turns out it was really only an issue on play.golang.org. I thought I tested it locally as well but I had another look now and yes on my local machine everything is correct.

Comment: Why do you think this is wrong?  As I write this comment, the time is 1398352146, a mere 442 seconds after you ran the output posted above.  What's wrong with your output?

Comment: just compare the result of `www.unixtimestamp.de` with the one `time.Now().Unix()` gives you. Also compare it to the one provided via dev tools. Take a look at the screenshots.

Comment: Time is frozen on play.golang.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Unix()` does produce a Unix timestap: The number of seconds since the epoch.
I think the documentation http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Unix is pretty clear here.

Maybe you are not interested in a Unix timestamp but some human readable time? In that case use `Format()`: http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format

And: The playground has only synthetic time. Absolute values on the playground do not correspond to UTC.

Comment: yes but compare the result of `www.unixtimestamp.de` with the one `time.Now().Unix()` gives you. Take a look at the screenshots.

Comment: I get the same falsy results on my local machine.

Comment: Then your local clock is wrong. Go reports the time from the OS.